# Anyway to get return value of c program from command line?

Tags: c, linux

I understand if I write a bash script I can get the return value, but is there anyway to get the return value without scripting, and just command line?

Comment: Exactly the same way as in a script.

Comment: Thanks Mat I got it working. As I'm sure you can tell I'm pretty new to developing in linux.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Yes, the same way you'd do in a Bash script. Run your program like this:

```
./your_program; echo $?
```

Comment: To point out the essence of this answer: BASH stores the return value of the previously run command in the variable `$?`.

Comment: -1.  The `&&` means you'll only ever get a 0 response - `echo` won't get run unless `your_program` succeeds.

Comment: What?  The whole point is to find the exit status of the program, right?  Your code only gets the exit status on success.  If you already know it succeeded, why bother checking?  Anyway, your update is fine - downvote removed.

Comment: @Carl: ahhhh, ok. I see your point now, and you're right. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 11):

In light of the invalidation of the previous answer (good point, Carl Norum), let me re-phrase my comment as an answer:

BASH stores the return value of the previously run command in the variable `$?`. This is independent of the programming langauge used to write said command (the command can also be a shell internal).