# What should I do to get the whole return value of c-program from command line?

Tags: c, bash, unix, return

I have a simple C-program `"./my_program"`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc , char **argv) {


   unsigned int return_result = 0x474;
   printf("return_result = %d = 0x%x \n",return_result,return_result);
   return return_result;

}
```

As a result, this program prints:

```
return_result = 1140 = 0x474
```

I want to get a return value of c-program within bash script.
According to this link
[Anyway to get return value of c program from command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8230265/anyway-to-get-return-value-of-c-program-from-command-line)
I should get this variable from $?

But when I launch such commands consequence:

```
./my_program
echo $?
```

I get

```
116
```

It is obviously, that 116 = 0x74 (the lowest byte).
But I'd like to get the whole unsigned int value.
What is wrong? What should I do to get the whole return value of c-program from command line? This is not about only "unsigned int" type. What should I do in case if I created some complicated type, for example, - structure.

I tried this:

```
return ((unsigned int) return_result_section_size);
```

It doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Exit codes on Unix are [restricted to a single byte](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status#Unix). If you want to output more, you could write it to stdout or to a file instead.

Then why does the C standard decree that `main` returns `int` and not `char`? I have no idea...

Comment: Probably because it's common to use `int` for numbers that do not need anything larger. For the same reason it's `int argc` and not `unsigned int argc`

Comment: Just because Unix restricts exit codes to a single byte doesn't mean that the standard should force the same restriction onto other platforms.

Comment: As for why `main` started off returning an `int`, I'd guess: 1. It's more natural to return the platform's native integer type; 2. Implicit `int`.

Comment: @jamesdlin: The standard does not impose restrictions, but allows flexibility and reflects the way multiple platforms work. The standard only respects two valid return values from main: EXIT_SUCCESS and EXIT_FAILURE.  Any other value is implementation defined.  This allows some platforms to return only the last byte returned.  An implementation is free to do whatever it wants, as long as EXIT_SUCCESS and 0 are treated as success, and EXIT_FAILURE is treated as a failure.  Requiring the value returned from main to be available would be a significant restriction.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: Uh, that was kind of my point. The question (paraphrased) was "why doesn't `main` return `char` instead?", and my response was that doing so would restrict other platforms.

Answer (score 0):

The value returned from main can be printed using echo $? after you are done with the execution. The return value from main is generally used to indicate the execution status.
The max value is limited to 512. If you try to return a greater value than 512, 512%val would be set in $?.

Comment: May be, you say about "The max value is limited to 255"? I've just tried to return 474. The result isn't 474.

Comment: Magic would be required to have a max of 512. And your formula is wrong. It should be `val%MAX`.

Comment: hmm... I think I was wrong for the max value. The max value is limited to a byte - 255.

Comment: Edit your answer so that reading comments wouldn't be required.