# return(sizeof(array)) gives unexpected result

Tags: c, arrays, return-value, sizeof

I wrote the following program to determine the size of a static array.  When I ran it, I got a result I can't explain.  I've done some searching on stackexchange and google, but nothing I've read has given me a hint.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int arrSize, intSize, elemSize;
  int input[9][9];
  arrSize = sizeof(input);
  intSize = sizeof(int);
  elemSize = sizeof(input[0]);
  printf("Array: %d, Element: %d, Int: %d\n", arrSize, elemSize, intSize);
  return sizeof(input);
}
```

When I compile and run this program, I get the following result (using linux):

```
./a.out ; echo $?
Array: 324, Element: 36, Int: 4
68
```

I see from http://c-faq.com/malloc/sizeof.html that `sizeof` is computed at compile time, and if I change the return to `return sizeof(input[0])` I get `36` which is expected, and I get `4` if I change it to `return sizeof(input[0][0])` as expected.  So why does `sizeof(input)` give `68` in the return, but when stored it gives the expected `324`?

Comment: Shell return values are probably max `256` ... `324%256 = 68`.

Comment: You are correct, I didn't think to check for shell limitations.  This is answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10479446/what-should-i-do-to-get-the-whole-return-value-of-c-program-from-command-line

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [exit code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status#Unix) for your system must be max `255` we can see that `324 % 256 = 68`.

Comment: It's not the shell that imposes that limit, though the shell does report the returned value (in `$?` if you're using a Bourne-like shell, `$status` if you're using a csh-like shell).

Comment: @KeithThompson Thank you, I just realized that, I adjusted my answer.

Answer (score 4):

After a child process terminated, its parent process could get the status information of this child process by

```
waitpid(-1, &status, 0);
```

And the return status could be extracted from `status` by `WEXITSTATUS(status)`, according to [`waitpid(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid) this macro

> returns the exit status of the child. This consists of **the least significant 8 bits** of the status argument that the child specified in a call to `exit(3)` or `_exit(2)` or as the argument for a return statement in `main()`.

Therefore, if your `main()` returns 324, the return code you get from shell would be `324 % 256`, i.e. 68.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour I think Linux would imply `& 255`.

Answer (score 0):

From the bash shell and scripting language reference documentation's "Exit status" section:[2]
The exit status of an executed command is the value returned by the waitpid system call or equivalent function. Exit statuses fall between 0 and 255, though, as explained below, the shell may use values above 125 specially. Exit statuses from shell builtins and compound commands are also limited to this range. Under certain circumstances, the shell will use special values to indicate specific failure modes.
For more information go to:[Exit status in Unix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status#Unix)

That's why your program is giving this output because 324 is the size of array but shell only can show up to 256 so

```
324%256=68;
```

If you want to output more, you could write it to stdout or to a file instead.