# In ant how to check if a file has been added to a Mercurial repository?

Tags: ant, mercurial

I want to write an ant task to check if the file was added to the Mercurial repository. But I don't know how to write the condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the status from a file by simply call [`hg status filename`](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/status) on that file. The returning string starts with some codes that shows the status of the file:

```
$ hg help status
...
  M = modified
  A = added
  R = removed
  C = clean
  ! = missing (deleted by non-hg command, but still tracked)
  ? = not tracked
  I = ignored
    = origin of the previous file listed as A (added)
...
$ hg status
A a.txt
A dir/c.txt
? b.txt
$ hg status a.txt
A a.txt
$ hg status b.txt
? b.txt
```

You can also check the location of the file in Mercurial control, if the file is under Mercurial control then the [`hg locate filename`](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/locate) returns the name of the file, nothing otherwise. Or may be by the [returning value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8230265/anyway-to-get-return-value-of-c-program-from-command-line) of the program, 0 if match 1 otherwise.

```
$ hg locate
a.txt
dir/c.txt
$ hg locate a.txt
a.txt
$ hg locate b.txt
$
$ echo $?
1
```

And you can also check if the file is in the manifest list, as [`hg manifest`](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/manifest) prints the list of version controlled files:

```
$ hg manifest
a.txt
dir/c.txt
```